# Lubuntu vs Debian LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, debian

Between Debian with LXDE installed and Lubuntu which is more lightweight? By lightweight I mean less RAM usage, power efficient, small amount of space taken up, startup speed, speed of installed applications, speed of the default operations, etc. Is there any significant difference between the two?

**EDIT:**

I have installed Debian with LXDE. It seems to me in my opinion more customizable, faster (responsive and less memory usage), and more lightweight than Lubuntu. Also, it makes much less disk usage noise. Though installing was harder I really like Debian.

Comment: I think it will be hard for anyone to provide you with accurate data. Debian and Ubuntu are very similar... I'd worry about other things, but if you are obsessed over benchmarks, try searching at Phoronix.

Comment: @SamuelSantana I got nothing searching there. Also, there isn't much on google either. But, can you tell me that Lubuntu and Debian LXDE are both lightweight?

Comment: @DKBose Alright. Time to go get my USB drive.

Comment: Yes, both are lightweight. Even if one can also install a normal LXDE  for Ubuntu, I prefer Lubuntu because it has better defaults for me. I used crunchbang a while ago and in my **subjective** opinion, it was more responsive on my old box. Crunchbang propper was discontinued, but a couple of projects picked up its development: Bunsenlabs and Crunchbang++, although I haven't tried those.

Comment: Crunchbang may have been lighter on resources, but it was more spartan and it didn't use LXDE, it only used Openbox (and other select components). So the difference may have rested more in the Desktop Environment than in the OS itself.

Comment: Wait... if I open task manager on Lubuntu (installed on my laptop), will the RAM usage be similar to if I booted up from a USB?

Comment: No, the live session will consume more memory.

Comment: @SamuelSantana How I will test which one is lighter then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54473/discussion-between-samuel-santana-and-6equj5).

Comment: Thanks to @SamuelSantana I have successfully installed Debian! It is great! (read edit in original post)